# リストの要素を分割

Tags: python

```
list1 = ['12:00～15:00', '18:00～23:30', '12:00～15:00', '18:00～24:00']
```

を

```
list1 = ['12:00','15:00', '18:00','23:30', '12:00','15:00', '18:00','24:00']
```

にしたいです。splitでやってみたんですが、リストは指定できないとエラーが出ます。何かやり方はありますか？

```
list1 = ['12:00～15:00', '18:00～23:30', '12:00～15:00', '18:00～24:00']
split('～', list1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str.split` は`str`型に対するメソッドであるため、リストに対して使うことはできません。

このため、 `map(lambda x:x.split("〜"), list1)` として、 `list1` の各要素に対して `str.split` を実行するのがよいでしょう。

記載のような出力が欲しい場合、 `functools.reduce` と組み合わせて以下のように結果を得ることができます。

```
from functools import reduce

list1 = ['12:00～15:00', '18:00～23:30', '12:00～15:00', '18:00～24:00']
print(list(reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, map(lambda x: x.split('～'), list1))))
# => ['12:00', '15:00', '18:00', '23:30', '12:00', '15:00', '18:00', '24:00']
```